# Regex end matching

Tags: regex

I need to match a date expression at the end of a string, for example "`USE OF VARIOUS INSTRUMENTS   3/18/2023`"

The pattern I use is: `\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/](\d{2}|d{4})$`

When I run it, it fails. But if I remove the `$` symbol from the end of the pattern, I get a match.

For the purposes of learning and the code I am writing, I don't want a match if the date occurs anywhere but at the end. I don't understand why it fails so I am asking for help. Thank you

Edit
I think I see why it fails. It matches the short year first, which is not at the end. This would have worked only if the test string had a 2-digit year at the end. So my question would be, how do I get it to match the longer of the 2 formats?

Comment: `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$`

Comment: This? `\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/](\d{4}|\d{2})$`

Comment: The way you have it works for most languages. Your are missing "\" to make it `\d` in the very last.  See https://regex101.com/r/XxXe7L/1

Comment: I needed it to be flexible so that it also catches 2-digit year dates

Answer (score 0):

First you didn't escape and it's one of the reasons

```
\d{1,2}[\-\/]\d{1,2}[\-\/](\d{2}){1,2}$
```

Second You can use repeats to achieve this:

```
(\d{1,2}[\-\/]){2}(\d{2}){1,2}$
```

And Also You can add this to prevent any kind of whitespaces at the end:

```
(\d{1,2}[\-\/]\d{1,2}[\-\/](\d{2}){1,2})\s*$
```

I think it's more classy!

Comment: Thank you. That works. I am using vbscript and the forward slashes dont need to be escaped so \d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2,4}$ works as well (minor point)

Comment: Keep in mind this will also match 3 digits at the end, which depending on your needs you may not want to match

Comment: That is the reason I chose (\d{2}|\d{4}) over \d{2,4}. Maybe I should have done (\d{2}\b|\d{4}\b)

Comment: @JonWayn maybe your right about vbscript but i'm sure you sould escape `-` n the `[]`. Check the answer I fixed your year issue. accept it if it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Alijvhr  I have tested it with and without escaping hyphens and it makes no difference. Your solution is spot right on. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your original regex is `\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/](\d{2}|d{4})$` and the last `d` is registering as the character `d` rather than digit because it is missing the `\`. Just add the `\` to it and it should be fixed:

```
\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/](\d{2}|\d{4})$
```